# tf slices with lambda layer only uses last index

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

## TLDR

---

*My for lambda layers to get tensor slices only get the last column of data.*

I have a **(Batch_size, R)** shape tensor that I will be running through an embedding layer for each of the R features seperately.  I wrote the following code to split the input (Batch_size, R) shaped tensor into R (None,) slices.

```
R=2
inp = tf.keras.Input(shape = (R,), dtype=tf.int32)

SLICES = []
for i in range(R):
    slice_ = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda a: a[:,i], name=f"slice_{i}", dtype=tf.int32)(inp)
    SLICES.append(slice_)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs= inp, outputs = SLICES)
```

Running `tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, show_dtype=True)` makes it appear that the code works.  Running data into the model shows that there is a problem: the model takes the last feature and copies it for all layers.

```
input_ = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
model.predict(input_)
```

> [array([2, 4, 6], dtype=int32), array([2, 4, 6], dtype=int32)]

##### Approach 1

I "fixed" the problem in the R=2 case by getting rid of the for loop and writing each layer by hand.

```
slice1 = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda a: a[:,0], name=f"first_slice", dtype=tf.int32)(inp)
slice2 = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda a: a[:,1], name=f"second_slice", dtype=tf.int32)(inp)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs= inp, outputs = [slice1, slice2])
input_ = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
model.predict(input_)
```

> [array([1, 3, 5], dtype=int32), array([2, 4, 6], dtype=int32)]

This is clearly undesirable for any number of reasons.

##### Approach 2

Another approach is to do the embedding on the raw features.  Unfortunately, I have a CutMix like layer in front of the embedding operation, preventing me from embedding the raw features.

---

How can I get the for loop to correctly copy each slice of the tensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your first block of codes not working is you need to write the lambda function like this instead: `lambda a,k=i: a[:,k]`

```
R=2
inp = tf.keras.Input(shape = (R,), dtype=tf.int32)

SLICES = []
for i in range(R):
    slice_ = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda a,k=i: a[:,k], name=f"slice_{i}", dtype=tf.int32)(inp)
    SLICES.append(slice_)

model = tf.keras.Model(inp, SLICES)

input_ = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
print(model.predict(input_))
```

Outputs:

```
[array([1, 3, 5], dtype=int32), array([2, 4, 6], dtype=int32)]
```